# Want to make iteration in two dates related to other data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, sql-server-2008, recursive-query

i have a view in sql server database that has the attendance for employee and the data stored like this

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
ID   | EmpID |  Name   |  ArrivalTime | LeavingTime | DayDate
------------------------------------------------------------------
1    |  5    | Hassan  | 9.00AM       | 5.50PM      | 19-11-2010
------------------------------------------------------------------
1    |  5    | Hassan  | 8.50AM       | 5.00PM      | 20-11-2010
------------------------------------------------------------------
1    |  5    | Hassan  | 8.30AM       | 4.54PM      | 23-11-2010
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

. And his start date in this company is stored in main EmployeeTable as StartDate Column and His End Date Also
I want to get absence days for this employee based on the data above, and it must start with StartDate Stored in EmployeeTable And End with EndDate Stored either if he has EndDate. 
for example this Employee start work with us on 20-10-2010
and his first day in the attendance table is 5-11-2010 i want all these days mentioned in the view day by day like

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
ID   | EmpID |  Name   | AbsenceDay
------------------------------------------------------------------
1    |  5    | Hassan  | 21-10-2010
------------------------------------------------------------------
1    |  5    | Hassan  | 22-10-2010
------------------------------------------------------------------
1    |  5    | Hassan  | 23-10-2010
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and so on 
and also

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
ID   | EmpID |  Name   | AbsenceDay
------------------------------------------------------------------
1    |  5    | Hassan  | 21-11-2010
------------------------------------------------------------------
1    |  5    | Hassan  | 22-11-2010
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

the absence day from AttendanceTable
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you want all dates for which an employee did not attend within its employement period.

One option is to use a recursive query to generates the list of days of employements, and then filter it with `not exists`.

```
with cte as (
    select empID, name, startDate, endDate from employees
    union all
    select empID, name, dateadd(day, 1, startDate), endDate 
    from cte 
    where startDate < endDate
)
select empID, name, startDate absenceDay
from cte c
where not exists (
    select 1 from attendances a where a.empID = c.empID and a.dayDate = c.startDate
)
```

If employment periods span over more than 3 months, you can add `option (maxrecursion 0)` at the very end of the query.

Comment: in large a mount of data it produces this error  ```The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.```

Comment: @HassanAhmed: you need to add `option (maxrecursion 0)` to your query - see my edit.

Comment: how to create it as a view with ```option``` it get me error ```Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'option'.```